# Determining whether a 3-dimensional equations creates a horizontal or non-horizontal plane?

Tags: calculus, 3d, coordinate-systems

I am learning about graphing 3-dimensional shapes on x,y,z coordinates axis and am understanding everything for the most part. However, the thing that is continuously tripping me up is distinguishing the difference between horizontal and non horizontal planes and I am sure there is a general rule to follow, but I do not understand it visually.

Here are some examples I have seen that ask the type of question whether it is a horizontal or non-horizontal plane.

$$
Example (2): z = y^{2} - 2x^{2}
$$

$$
Example (3): z = x^{2}
$$

I am ruling that example 2 is a hyperbolic paraboloid. 
[image: Hyper Parab Graph for ex) 2]

This is the graph for example 2.

Comment: The first three examples are not planes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one plane equation number 4 with normal $(2,3,-1)$. The plane is $ax+by+cz=d$ with normal $(a,b,c)$ which helps you to answer your questions
The graph of 3 is[image]

Comment: I just realized, I misunderstood the form of the equation. The second equation was supposed to read z=4. I understand the first equation is a cylinder and the equation of the plane does make sense. I am confused on what equation 2 & 3 represent.

Comment: I am seeing is as a hyperbolic paraboloid, Semsem.

Comment: i prepair a graph for you wait

Comment: and i graph 3 uh

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am assuming the first equation , I removed the others since I figured them out, is the hyperbolic paraboloid. What type of paraboloid is the one you graphed for me?

Comment: Here is a good [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraboloid)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12846/discussion-between-curiousfellow-and-semsem)

Comment: i tried but i face some some problems logging in

Comment: No worries. I am just wondering the type of graph z=x^2 is representing. Because it is not correct in terms of the graphs that we have discussed.

Comment: Uh i am sorry it is called a parabolic cylinder